# Analogue of Catalan numbers for non-associative but commutative products

Tags: co.combinatorics

The number of distinct products of $n$ elements in the free magma with one generator is given by the Catalan numbers $C(n)$, that can be defined with $C(1)=1$ and for $n>1$,
$$C(n)= \sum_{1\le k\le n-1} C(k)\cdot C(n-k).$$
A closed form of $C(n)$ is
$$C(n) = \binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{n+1}.$$

Let now $K(n)$ be the number of distinct products of $n$ elements in the free commutative magma with one generator. It seems that the series $K(n)$ can be defined with $K(1)=1$ and for $n > 1$,
$$K(n)= \sum_{1\le k\le [n/2]} K(k)\cdot K(n-k),$$
where $[n/2]$ is the greatest natural number less than $n/2$ ($[
\cdot]$ is the floor function). 
Question: is this correct and do we know a closed form for $K(n)$?

Comment: The $K(n)$ form https://oeis.org/A000992

Comment: OEIS names these numbers the "Half Catalan" numbers and gives no closed form for them

Comment: From the operadic point of view, the correct generating series is https://oeis.org/A001147 (for the underlying species of this operad).

Comment: Thanks F.C. OEIS AOO1147 is named double factorial of odd numbers and has a closed form

Comment: Are you overcounting at the first level of branching when $n$ is even?  It looks like you might want $\binom{K(n/2)}2 + K(n/2)$ in that case.  If so, is this also the count of rooted binary trees with $n$ leaves up to isomorphism?